# CPUs not working at 100%

Tags: 18.04, cpu, intel-cpu

I recently upgraded my system to a i58400, 16 gb ddr4 and as os jumped from 16.04 to 18.04.1.

Now im compiling Unreal Engine for Linux, so its supposed to be a heavy calculation and take many hours. My surprise is that watching the system monitor i meet:

[image]

Is there any tweak im missing, because my system is not working as fast as it can. Most cpus works at less than 50%. I also have read the history and its very similar to the image above.

Im not taking advantatge of my system's configuration.

Thanks in advance

Edit update: Image with cpu and iowaits...
[image]

Comment: Is it spending a lot of time in IO wait?

Comment: @DougSmythies dont know how to watch IO but im using a Samsung SSD 970 EVO PCI-E NVMe M.2 500 GB so i dont think so, and its only compiling no im making massive movements of files at the same time...

Comment: @DougSmythies ive updated the question, iowait is almost always 0% - 1%, some peaks at 4%, And cpu in global at 20% with some peaks arrive to 30%.

Comment: Have you checked to see that you can reach full saturation of your cpu with something like `for i in 1 2 3 4;do while: ;d do : ; done & done`?